# C# MongoDB Driver - Ignore fields on De-Serializing

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to retrieve the list of Booking collection.

Some of the collection have,

Case 1

```
 "Countries": [{
                "Destinations": [{
                    "Code": "CHX",
                    "Name": "French Alps"
                }],
                "Code": {
                    "_t": "JsonElement"
                },
                "Name": {
                    "_t": "JsonElement"
                }
            }]
```

and some of them have,

Case 2

```
 "Countries": [{
                "Destinations": [{
                    "Code": "DXB",
                    "Name": "Dubai"
                }],
                "Code": "AE",
                "Name": "United Arab Emirates"
            }]
```

Note that `code` and `name` fields.

and the model for retrieve list is

```
    {
        public List<DestinationDocument> Destinations { get; set; } = new List<DestinationDocument>();

        public string Code { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to to ignore the `code` and `name` when they are not string (i.e I want to ignore `code` and `name` of  case 1 . but not `Destinations` of  case 1 ).

How can I do that using mongoDb driver.

I tried `SetIgnoreExtraElements`. but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to control the way MongoDB .NET deserializes your data is probably to create your own serializer and return `null` whenever it encounters anything different than `BsonType.String`. It can be done in two steps. Define your custom deserialization logic:

```
public class IgnoreDocumentSerializer : SerializerBase<string>
{
    public override string Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        var serializer = BsonSerializer.LookupSerializer(typeof(string));
        if(context.Reader.CurrentBsonType == BsonType.String)
        {
            return (string)serializer.Deserialize(context, args);
        }

        if (context.Reader.CurrentBsonType == BsonType.Document)
        {
            context.Reader.ReadRawBsonDocument();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

and decorate your model properties with `BsonSerializer` attribute:

```
public class Country
{
    public List<DestinationDocument> Destinations { get; set; } = new List<DestinationDocument>();

    [BsonSerializer(typeof(IgnoreDocumentSerializer))]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [BsonSerializer(typeof(IgnoreDocumentSerializer))]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```